Are these gaps in house framing up to code?
Are these framing issues up to code?

Studs on both load bearing and not that are not touching the mud sill:



Bowed studs were "fixed" by letting in a 2x4, but there are gaps above and below the let-in 2x4:




FYI, house wrap isn't a "vapor barrier". Quite the opposite, in fact--its purpose is to let vapor pass.

Does anyone have an opinion? is not a question about house construction ... BTW what use is a yes answer anyway?

A yes answer would mean I need to let the guys slide. A no answer would mean this framing is incorrect and needs to be repaired

My suggestion is a hiring a building inspector to identify problem areas that require remediation. Studs not touching on load bearing walls are bad; over time it will sag and close the gap, but it will crack drywall on the interior. At a minimum, it should be sistered. The other items in your post are not something that would concern me from a structural/safety standpoint.

I did hire another 3rd party inspector and he agreed about the studs not touching but nobody was sure about they way the bowed studs were fixed on load bearing walls if it was acceptable or not because code is kind of grey on notches. Not more than 25% I believe it is but since the 2x4 is let in but not let in snugly we weren’t sure how to proceed

That is what happens when you bolt a bottom plate down to a less-than-perfectly-flat floor. Happens all the time.

Code doesn't really address quality issues like this. It's concerned with structure, not fitment. Individual states have varying laws that protect new home buyers from severe structural issues, should that occur.
Here are some general thoughts on what you've shown us.

That isn't a "mud sill". It's just a bottom wall plate. If the studs were load-bearing they'd be pressed tight. I suspect that they're partition walls, and therefore I'm not concerned. In a worst-case scenario, there's settling after drywall work is done and some mild cracking. The simple fix to prevent that is to drive some shims in the gaps; pairs from opposing directions would fill the void nicely. Construction adhesive would keep them in place.

The purpose of the let-in horizontal member is to stiffen the wall on the perpendicular horizontal axis. That does not depend on a snug fit. Again, not a concern.



It's called "rough framing" for a reason. There is no code that specifies gaps between framing members. You may be surprised at the loads that have been carried, for the better part of a century or longer, by a few nails alone.

The studs pictured have bracing that runs from the roof rafters down to the top plate above the gaps. There are also gaps on the studs on the exterior walls. And I only mentioned about the key in bracing because I was told by the framing crew that’s how they fixed their bowed studs

Gaps in exterior walls can be supported by the wall sheathing. That's not uncommon. Because such a wall is a large system it's normal for specific areas to be lightly loaded. Again, if the weight of the house hasn't closed the gaps they're probably not going to close.
